# Is it mandatory to use FCM in iOS Client app for receiving remote notification if the server side uses FCM for sending notifications

Tags: ios, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to implement remote notifications in my iOS application. The server side has used Firebase Cloud Messaging for sending the notification. Is it mandatory to use Firebase Cloud Messaging in iOS Client app for receiving remote notification?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to use FCM in client side. For sending a notification to a specific user, needs to store users FCM token in server side.

```
    guard FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() == nil else {            
                if let token = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
                    // send token to server
                }
}
```